# No Magento como adicionar classe em lista dependendo dos atributos a serem exibidos?

Tags: php, magento

Tenho um `foreach` que me traz todos os filhos de um atributo X, e preciso adicionar uma classe específica na lista `<ul>` para poder formatar por CSS conforme o atributo Y. Porém, não estou conseguindo adicionar o nome do atributo na classe.

Abaixo um exemplo retirado de app/design/frontend/base/default/tempplate/catalog/layer/filter.phtml

```php
<ol class="filters filter-type">
<?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
    <li>
        <?php if ($_item->getCount() > 0): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>"><?php echo $_item->getLabel() ?></a>
        <?php else: echo $_item->getLabel() ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($this->shouldDisplayProductCount()): ?>
        (<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)
        <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ol>
```

---

Em uma página de categoria com filtro, eu quero que ao carregar os atributos dos produtos esses blocos tenham uma classe específica que identifique.

Exemplo:

**Tamanho**

- 38
- 39
- 40

**Sexo**

- Masculino
- Feminino

**Preço**

- De 30 a 40
- De 50 a 80
- De 100 a 200

Onde cada bloco  recebe uma classe: *filter-tamanho*, *filter-sexo*, *filter-preco*, só que eu não sei qual atributo ele irá trazer e preciso que isso seja dinâmico.

Comment: Amigo, nos de algum código para melhor exemplificar o que você precisa.

Comment: Amigo, se você passar qual é a condição exata para inserir a classe e em qual elemento, podemos passar qual o melhor código para fazer isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom, vamos tomar umas suposições então pra conseguir mostrar um código viável.

```php
<?php
    $produtos['tipo1'] = [
        // Produtos tipo um
    ];

    $produtos['tipo2'] = [
        // Produtos tipo dois
    ];

    $produtos['tipo3'] = [
        // Produtos tipo três
    ];

    foreach ($produtos as $tipo => $listaProdutos): ?>

    <ol class="filters filter-<?= $tipo ?>">

        <?php foreach ($listaProdutos as $produto): ?>

            <li><?= $produto->nome ?></li>
            <li><?= $produto->descricao ?></li>
            <li><?= $produto->valor ?></li>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </ol>
<?php
    endforeach;
?>
```

É isso que me vez na cabeça agora, ajuda você?

Att

Answer (score -3):

Se entendi direito, o que vc quer é adicionar uma classe no `<li>` caso esse filtro tenha algum produto pra ser trazido, certo?

Acho que ficaria assim:

```php
<li<?php echo ($_item->getCount() > 0):?' class="temitens"':'';?>>
```

Dessa forma, se tiver itens ele adiciona uma classe **temitens**, do contrario nao faz nada.